# Can't get the Slideshare icon to work

Tags: font-awesome

For some reason, I can't seem to get the Slideshare icon (f1e7) to work.

Every other icon in the font seems fine - and I made sure my installed fonts were all from the latest 4.2 archive.

Any ideas?

TIA,

Adam.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue currently. I think this may be an issue with the font files, because when I comment out the sources so only the .svg is used, the icon shows up fine.

Until the issue is resolved, I would recommend using the .svg of the slideshare icon, and implementing it using icomoon.